# Error in json_decode when receive data via post request

Tags: php, json, api

I am accessing an api via php that returns data in json format and after that I use the json_decode() function to transform the returned string to json. The problem is that when I use json decode it doesn't return anything. I have had this problem before, and I know that last time I solved it by changing the way I did this post request to the api, but I don't remember how I did it. Can anyone help me?

NOTE: When I put the returned string inside the json decode it works, but when I put it inside a variable and try json_decode() it breaks.

Post request:

```
public static function post($url, $username, $password)
    {
        $params = array(
            'needsNicknamesAudios' => true
        );

        $jsonData = json_encode($params);

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $headers = array(
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("$username:$password") 
        );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        logText('result in curl', $res);

        return $res;
    }
```

Log of responses:

[image]

snippet where make the request:

```
$rs = json_decode(Curl::post(baseUrl . "users/auth/", $cpfOrCnpj, $password));

logText('rs in login', $rs);
```

example of string json returned of API:

```
{"auth":{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NzExMTQ2MzgsImlhdCI6MTY3MTExMzczOCwic3ViIjoiMTY4MiJ9.8dgJc7gcSk4CINjeI3qOA3evLm3--8iDROPsLRCfuaQ","expInSecs":1671114638},"user":{"id":1682,"document":"44105337000139","name":"Márcio Valim","email":"marciogsvalim@gmail.com","phone":"5524993047304","confirmedEmail":false,"blockMessage":"Esse aparelho foi perdido. Por favor, use as informações de contato abaixo para devolver ao dono.","isCurrentPasswordUsedForLongTime":false,"currentPasswordUseIntervalInMonths":0},"licenses":[{"id":2729,"exp":"2023-12-15T12:55:15.000Z","autoRenewal":false,"type":"single","activated":true,"blocked":false,"device":{"imei":"354476112827609","brand":"Samsung","comercial":"Test model","technical":"Test technical model"},"phone":null,"nicknameAudioUrl":null},{"id":2730,"exp":"2023-12-15T12:55:43.000Z","autoRenewal":false,"type":"single","activated":true,"blocked":false,"device":{"imei":"350812850097258","brand":"Samsung","comercial":"Test model","technical":"Test technical model"},"phone":null,"nicknameAudioUrl":null}]}
```

Comment: does logText properly manage printing ojects? try to make something like this in order to test it `logText('rs in login', print_r($rs, true));` to be sure that $rs is actually empty... and it's not a logText() problem.

Comment: Still null When the json_decode() works, the logText(rs login) returns something like this [user] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1682
            [document] => 44105337000139
            [name] => Márcio Valim
            [email] => marciogsvalim@gmail.com
            [phone] => 5524993047304
            [confirmedEmail] => 
            [blockMessage] => Esse aparelho foi perdido. Por favor, use as informações de contato abaixo para devolver ao dono.
            [isCurrentPasswordUsedForLongTime] => 
            [currentPasswordUseIntervalInMonths] => 0
        )

Comment: Probably there are some cases when your api, for some reasons, doesn't respond with a proper json. try to manage it printing the response that it is not a proper json.

Comment: I just fixed the problem. In the post function I took out the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); and it worked, but thank you very much for your help Gicu Aftene

Comment: I wast just writing that in fact you have all headers in your response that should contain only your json lol